# Woocommerce not loading the data in Tax standard rates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, standards, tax, rates

may i know what would be the possible issue for the woocommerce tax in the standard rates and keeps saying loading and it is not loading the data. though this was setup before. I have tried disabling plugins and it is still not working.

[image]

i have also check the database for possible missing table, but the table for wp_woocommerce_tax_rates_locations are present.

[image]

Comment: Make a DB backup first… Then you should try remove all data going to WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Delete WooCommerce tax rates… Then try to set it manually again in Tax settings rates.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply. i have tried what you have suggest and it is still keeps saying loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i have resolved the issue, what i did was after Deactivating all plugins and going to WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Delete WooCommerce Tax rates as suggested by @LoicTheAztec and lastly i deactivated WooCommerce itself and Activated again. and inputted the tax rates back. This solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: hi, i think yes, but i guess it needs to deactivate and activate woocommerce.

Comment: Because when you have updated Woocommerce, you have missed database update… So de-activating/re-activating it has done this…